# Calculating Circuit Delay

Tags: delay

I am trying to understand why the calculating the last delay is \$max(t,mt)+2t\$. I suppose thats derived from \$max(max(t,mt), t)+t\$? But how do you extract the \$t\$ from \$max(..., t)\$ out.

[image]

**UPDATE**

I also dont get the next part ...

[image]

whats m? and how is \$S_i=max(t,mt)+t\$ and \$C_{i+1}=max(t,mt)+2t\$ simplified to \$2t\$ and \$3t\$ respectively?

Comment: It's about the race between X/Y '0/0' inputs and C 'mt'

Comment: @kenny, what about them? I don't understand ... I also updated my question

Comment: max(x,y) takes the maximum of x or y and it's algebra

Comment: oh yes, I understand that part. What I dont understand is how I get \$C_{i+1}=max(t,mt)+2t\$. What I got, from my own understanding is \$C_{i+1}=max(max(t,mt)+t, mt)+t\$. How do I simplify down to \$C_{i+1}=max(t,mt)+2t\$? Also I dont get whats \$m\$ in the update. How do I simplify from \$C_{i+1}=max(t,mt)+2t\$ to \$C_5=9t\$ for example? I may know \$i\$ but not \$t\$?

Comment: @Brian Carlton - I previously removed the `homework` tag as it's *deprecated*, so I rolled back to that version.

Comment: @stevenvh  Do we have a definitive source of information on homework tag deprecation? I posted a question some time ago without it and it was added with explanation that EE is an exception to the global policy.

Comment: @AndrejaKo - It's been mentioned before in comment, but I couldn't say where. Could have been in meta. I have recently (this week) seen the tag removed by a mod. I've posted a [question](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/822/shouldnt-we-disallow-adding-deprecated-tags) about it in meta.

Comment: @AndrejaKo see http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/115/what-meta-tags-on-er-should-be-axed/116#116

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the first question is that if you take *max(max(t,mt)+t,mt)+t*, you can bring the t in the inner brackets, obtaining *max(t+t, mt+t)*: since the latter is always bigger than mt (unless you have a negative t) you can simplify with *max(t+t, mt+t)+t* and then take out again the *+t* and obtain the value shown.

For the second part, m is again the coefficient that multiplies t: let's take your case.

m=7, so *max(t, 7t)+2t=9t* as shown.

It's easy!

Answer (score 0):

With the 'mt' for the C input, this just means that the input isn't ready until *mt* time after the X and Y inputs. Each gate adds propagation delay *t*, so this just tells you that Cin was produced by *m* gates.

About those two gates that produce Cout, and the nested max() -

max(max(mt,t), t) reduces to max(mt,t) :

let f(m,t) = max(max(mt,t),t)
let g(m,t) = max(mt,t)

if mt > t, then
 f(mt,t) equals max(max(mt,t), t) equals max(mt, t) equals mt
 g(mt,t) equals max(mt, t) equals mt

if mt <= t, then
f(m,t) equals max(max(mt,t), t) equals max(t, t), equals t
g(m,t) equals max(mt, t) equals t

So, for any m and t, functions f() and g() are equivalent. I.e., max(max(mt,t),t) reduces to max(mt,t) !

Now, with that out of the way, you should see that the *t* wasn't extracted from the max() expression; that *t* delay was incurred by the rightmost AND gate. It was the inputs to that AND gate that were ready at time max(mt, t), and its output was ready *t* units after that, for max(mt,t) + t. Likewise, the OR that produces the C output adds another *t* of propagation delay, giving you the max(mt,t) + 2t result.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have,

`Ci+1=max(max(t,mt)+t,mt)+t`

Start as far in as possible:

`max(t,mt)+t` = mt+t

And make your way outward.

`max(max(t,mt)+t,mt)` => `max(mt+t,mt)` = mt+t

`mt+t +t` = mt + 2t

`Ci+1 = mt + 2t`

Where you could of course retain what you have as the solution:

`Ci+1 = max(t,mt) + 2t`

But after substitution, `max(t, mt)` will always evaluate to `mt`. I have never done this sort of thing before with circuit delays, but I assumed `mt` was just a constant scaled `t`. As such, just carry out the algebra where `max(a,b)`
 returns the max of the two arguments.